# Probability of a countable intersection

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

It's well know and easy to prove that given a **finite** number of events $A_1,\dots,A_n$ we can factorize the probability of their intersection as:
$$\mathbb{P}(A_1\cap\dots\cap A_n)=\mathbb{P}(A_1)\mathbb{P}(A_2|A_1)\dots\mathbb{P}(A_n|A_1\cap \dots  \cap A_n)$$
I was wondering if this remains true for a sequence of events, i.e. can we factorize a countable intersection in the same way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just take limit on both sides to get $P(\cap_n A_n)=P(A_1)\prod_{k=2}^{\infty} P(A_k|A_1,A_2,...,A_{k-1})$.

Comment: So you are using sequential continuity of the probability the pass the limit inside P in the LHS?

Comment: Right, the events $A_1\cap A_2\cap...\cap A_n$ decrease to the event $\cap_n A_n$ so we can pass to the limit.